# Remove horizontal scroll bar Godaddy html

Tags: html, css, builder

I am currently building a website for [Bearskin Group](http://BearskinGroup.com) ....

The site is pretty much done, I am creating it with the GoDaddy online builder....

BUT - I have this stupid horizontal bar scroll coming up that id like to diasble...

I have tried using:

```
style="overflow-x: hidden"
```

&

```
div {
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Can anyone help me remove this?

Thanks 
Dan

Comment: ha ha instead of pasting your email address try to post some code here.. so we can look.

Comment: SO Don't run like this, no code use of external accessible tool etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using huge width.

```
#wsb-element-233156931 .wsb-image-inner div {
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 2904px; /*remove it*/
}
```

**or**

change `overflow:auto` to `overflow:hidden` in class `wsb-canvas-page-container`

Also I noticed you are using image (check below), can't you remove the image or use a `background-color` to fill the color.

```
<div class="customStyle"><img style="width:2904px;height:60px;" alt="" src="//nebula.wsimg.com/b7fd20f21ba2c36e5ef9f39ea2613e8e?AccessKeyId=D238BA178C5B0342ADD7&amp;disposition=0&amp;alloworigin=1"></div>
```

Comment: i think he can't remove it. Its a ugly website builder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It turned out to be an element that was sticking out with an invisible box. You can define page restrictions but if a shape, text box or element is protruding into the edges it automatically overrides your restrictions and creates more room. Eliminating these should shrink your page back down to normal and eliminate the horizontal scroll.